# Selecting between valid and non-valid types

Tags: c++, c++11

If we have a template metafunction like `std::conditional`, we can "select" types based on a boolean compile-time condition. For example:

```
template < bool CONDITION, typename T, typename U >
struct conditional;

template < typename T, typename U > 
struct conditional < true, T, U >
{
    using type = T;
};

template < typename T, typename U > 
struct conditional < false, T, U >
{
    using type = U;
};

const bool whats_big = sizeof( int ) > sizeof( double );

using bigger_type = typename conditional<whats_big , int , double>::type;
```

My question is: **Is there any way to select between a valid type and an invalid type?**

Im currently implementing an event class. Events have a sender parameter and variable number of event args:

```
template<typename SENDER , typename... ARGS>
class event;
```

So functions with type `void(SENDER& , ARGS&...)` could be used as event handlers.
In that case the handlers are called passing a reference to the object wich have raised the event (Throught the sender param).
On the other hand, I want a way to allow sender member functions to be handlers of events, in other words, functions of type `void(SENDER::*)(ARGS&...)`.

The problem is that I cannot use a sentence like:

```
 using handler_type = typename conditional<std::is_class<SENDER>::value,void(SENDER::*)(ARGS&...) , void(SENDER& , ARGS&...)>::type;
```

Because in the case that `SENDER` is not a class type, the first type is invalid (Uses a pointer to a member of a non-class type).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with an extra level of indirection:

```
template <bool, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct sender_chooser
{
    using type = void(*)(T &, Args &...);
};

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct sender_chooser<true, T, Args...>
{
    using type = void (T::*)(Args &...);
};

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct sender_type
{
    using type =
        typename sender_chooser<std::is_class<T>::value, T, Args...>::type;
};
```

Usage:

```
sender_type<MySender, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3>::type
```

This is is either `void (MySender::*)(Arg1 &, Arg2 &, Arg3 &)` if `MySender` is a class type, or otherwise `void (*)(Sender &, Arg1 &, Arg2 &, Arg3 &)`.

(You might also want to allow unions.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Its exactly what I need. Only one question: Is not the variadic pack must be at the end of the template?

Comment: @Manu343726 If it is exactly what you need, perhaps you should accept is as an answer?

Comment: I was just waiting for his answer to my comment. Sorry