# Selecting between valid and non-valid non-type parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to replicate the answer to this question: [Selecting between valid and non-valid types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504860/selecting-between-valid-and-non-valid-types) but I can't figure out how to achieve this with a non-type template parameter pack.

For context, I'm trying to implement a templated multidimensional array

```
template<typename T, std::size_t CurrentDim, std::size_t... Dims>
class Array {
```

In the class, I'm trying to create a array of type T if Dims is empty and an an array of type Array<T, Dims...> if Dims is not empty. For example:

```
using SubType = std::conditional<sizeof...(Dims) == 0, T, Array<T, Dims...>>;        
SubType array[CurrentDim];
```

The problem is that if Dims is empty, the conditional fails with

```
error: too few template arguments for class template 'Array'
```

...since the second part of the conditional, which is invalid, is evaluated even though the check is false. Does anyone know how to achieve this? I know I could specialize my Array class but I believe that would require me to duplicate all my code?

Here's another related question: [std::conditional compile-time branch evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098278/stdconditional-compile-time-branch-evaluation)

Comment: I think you forgot to write the size of your `Array`: `Array<T, size!!!, Dims...>`

Comment: Wouldn’t size be the first element of Dims...?

Comment: Your template has 3 parameters: `template<typename T, std::size_t CurrentDim, std::size_t... Dims>`, you have to pass `T, CurrentDim` and `Dims`

Comment: And your `CurrentDim` is a parameter of your template so you can't write `SubType array[CurrentDim]`. I think thats not your intention (you are defining an array of an array, and not a simple array).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be partial specialization:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t CurrentDim, std::size_t... Dims>
class Array {
  Array<T, Dims...> array[CurrentDim];
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Dim>
class Array<T, Dim> {
  T array[Dim];
};
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this require me to duplicate all my code?

Comment: You could have a helper class that does this partial specialization trick and just provides a member typedef. Then the main class would refer to that typedef. [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/3qx3qbnq6)

Comment: Ahah! That example is perfect! Thank you! Do you want to update your answer with that example?